# Post slugs and images cannot have same name?

Tags: posts, permalinks, images, media-library, slug

If I go to Media Library and upload an image called `apple-pie.jpg`
And then I create a post called `www.domain.com/apple-pie/` 
The link does NOT take me to the post. Instead the link will take me to a page displaying the media (In other words, it uses a page template instead of single.php)

So does Wordpress NOT allow images and post slugs to be the same? How do I fix this problem? Do I have to rename all of my images?

Comment: Well, attachments are a post type so...

Comment: When I go to Media Library > Select an image > Click "view attachment page" > The URL is 
`http://127.0.0.1/?attachment_id=592` > I see the attachment page which uses a single.php template
----- However, when I go to view the post `http://127.0.0.1/apple-pie` > I see a page displaying the media (instead of a post) and it uses a page template -----
So are these two different types of "attachment pages" ? Why would WordPress make TWO attachment pages? And is it best practice to name images different from post slug?

Comment: This should be working. I have a website where I keep image name same as page slug and it works fine because attachments are post type and its slug is `attachment`. So either you are doing something wrong, using plugin or theme function. Otherwise it should work. Try it with disabled plugins or preferably on a fresh install with twentyfourteen theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress uses the attachment filename to create the attachment post slug.

If your file was named something else, there would not be any conflicts.

If you have your post permalinks set to `/%postname%/` , and you upload an image FIRST, and then create a post SECOND, then WordPress has to make a choice between the two when someone tries to access the Permalink.

To solve the issue, you would either have to change your permalink structure OR change the name of either the post or the attachment.

Comment: Ah I see. This makes sense now. Thanks!! If anyone is interested, as explained by Courtney, I uploaded image first which is the cause of the slug conflict. Usually I would create post first so I never encountered this issue til now.